# TIN Interpolation method in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, interpolation, tin

I am trying to interpolate 6 vector points in QGIS using TIN interpolation. However, I keep getting an error msg. For some unknown reason, it won't complete the interpolation. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please place all error messages in the Question body, not just in images (which are not searchable or legible on all devices.

Comment: What is posted to the Log Messages Panel?

Comment: Export the CSV layer to a vector format, reprojecting it to EPSG:3857 (because it is the reference in which your extent is defined). Make sure that the vector geometries are inside the extent, because it seems like not. Maybe they are, and the problem is with the CSV file or its CRS, so _export / reproject / verify its extent_ must solve the issue.